# Create Connection Between two post types

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I am creating a custom calendar plugin but I am stumped with the connection of post types.

I have a 2 post types "Calendars" and "Events".  I would like to create a metabox that contains a table just like the post type page along with the add post button to add a new event.

I have created the metabox using the following.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_meta_boxes' );
function add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'events_metabox', 'Events', 'display_events', 
     'plugin_calendar', 'normal' );
}

function display_events(){

    // Display table and add button.

}
```

I am also using ACF Pro to add fields to each post type if this makes it easier to do what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something very similar, also with Advanced Custom Fields. My project has 2 custom post types; Programs and Exercises. Like your Calendar and Events cpt, I have multiple Exercises linked to each Program. The way I do it is with Post Objects. I add Exercises as field type Post Object, filtered by post type, to the ACF Field Group. No meta boxes needed.

Comment: This wont work.  The Plan is to put a post type within a post type. By doing what you are it makes it harder on the customer.  We deal with a lot of people that do not work well with computers.  I was able to display the entire table on the page but now I have to figure out how to move it outside the form tag.

Comment: Are you using a child theme and cpt-template file to display your calendar post? Can you share a link to your current page view?

Comment: This is being developed as a plugin with a shortcode.  I dont have enough room here to explain how the system is working.